# On Export The Updated yAxis Title Is Lost

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

Our charts contain multiple series. We only allow one series to be visible in the chart at a time. When the chart first loads we set the title of the `yAxis` to the `series[0].name`:

```
chart {
...
events: {
    load: function () {
        this.options.yAxis[0].title.text = this.series[0].name;
        this.yAxis[0].setTitle({ text: this.series[0].name });
        this.yAxis[0].update({
            title: {
                text: this.series[0].name
            }
        });
    }
}
...
}
```

On the legend item click we do:

```
events: {
    legendItemClick: function (event) {
        var seriesIndex = this.index;
        var serie = this.chart.series;
        for (i = 0; i < serie.length; i++) {
            if (serie[i].index == seriesIndex) {
                serie[i].show();
                this.chart.options.yAxis[0].title.text = serie[i].name;
                this.chart.yAxis[0].setTitle({ text: serie[i].name });
            } else {
                serie[i].hide();
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

As the user clicks on each series in the legend the data set is updated and the `yAxis.title.text` is changed to reflect the `series.name` of the active series.

However, when we export the chart regardless of which series is active the `yAxis.title.text` is always the initially loaded value.

How can I get the chart export to have the correct title for the yAxis? I thought setting the `chart.options` would do this.

Representative [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wergeld/e9o7ek2a/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of setting first series title statically, you can use loop to find a visible serie and then update axis title. As a result in the exporting, you will achive your goal.

```
load: function () {

                var series = this.series,
                    yAxis = this.yAxis[0];

                $.each(series,function(i, serie) {
                    if(serie.visible) {
                        yAxis.setTitle({
                            text: serie.name
                        });
                    }
                });
 }
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/e9o7ek2a/3/